# Where is the i3status config file?

Tags: ubuntu

I have been using i3wm for some time on ubuntu server 20.04 and is great. However, I want to add CPU temperature to the i3status but I don't know where to find the i3status config file.
Any help would be appreciated! My i3wm version is 4.1.7.1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `cp /etc/i3status.conf ~/.config/i3status/config`
2. Edit the config file, e.g. `vim .config/i3status/config`
3. Restart i3 to see the changes, default key binding is `$mod+Shift+r`

See documentation at https://i3wm.org/i3status/manpage.html